# R - What Distribution Do My Data Have?

Tags: r, distributions

I have a Dataframe and am trying to figure out what distribution my variables have so i can decide on a model (lm, glm, gam). How would I do this? Is there any help that R can give me on this?

Simple plot() and looking at the data does not help.

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than `plot()`, I would probably use `hist()`...

Comment: run `?density()`
`?hist()`

Comment: This is a problem R is not going to solve for you. It is something you should understand from the nature of your data and what you are going to do with it.

Comment: Please tell us what applied problem you want to solve: How did you obtain your data, and what applied question do you wnat the data to help answer?

Comment: A linear model, a GLM or a GAM would be a model for the *conditional* distribution of the response, not the marginal distribution. A histogram or kernel density estimate of $y$ (which tells you about the marginal distribution of $y$) may be actively misleading about the shape of the conditional distribution. The suggestions of Damiano, Patrik and Dmitriy (the posted answer) all fall into this error. Edwin's and kjetil's comments are considerably more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have too low reputation for commenting, so, I try to get a simple answer. 
Suppose, you only could use tests like Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test for distribution testing by searching in the pool of basic distributions (normal, t-student, etc). 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

Comment: This isn't likely to be appropriate for identifying the *regression* models mentioned in the question because what matters are the conditional distributions, not the marginal distribution.